# Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/pgf/ color'

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I am trying to plot a chart using the following chart:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} % Pie chart library


\begin{frame}{Work}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.8}{
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \pie[
        color = {
            yellow!90!black, 
            green!60!black, 
            blue!60, 
            red!70,
            gray!70,
            teal!20},
        text = legend   % Add a legend
        ]   % Values:
        {
            20/Report Writing + Documentation,
            10/Reaction Wheel design,
            30/Components testing,
            40/HiL control algorithm testing and optimization
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{Work organisation. Source: Own.}
    \label{fig:work_pie_chart}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However I cannot render the pdf, it says

```
Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/pgf/ color', to which you passed 'yellow!90!black, green!60!black, blue!60, red!70, gray!70, teal!20', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Comment: your example doesn't compile at all as it misses the documentclass and \begin{document}/\end{document}. Beside this: obviously there is a space too much before color.

Comment: Sorry! I have missed the esstential part, I am going to reupload it!

Comment: It is still not complete, there is no `\end{document}` and  `\documentclass` should start the document, not come after `\usepackage`'s. The theme you're using is not available for others, so we cannot test it

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the insight, I was copying a snippet of the code and got messed! Now it should be okay I think!

Comment: You can remove all package except `tikz` and `pgf-pie`. The issue here is that spaces are being interpreted in `\pie[ ...]`, remove the line break before the `color` key, so you have `\pit[color={...}`  then it compiles for me. I'd guess it was trying to look for the key ` color` (note the space) and failed

Comment: I reported it in https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf-pie/issues/14, and have fixed it in code base.

Answer (score 5):

This example works

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} % Pie chart library

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Work}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \pie[color={yellow!90!black, 
            green!60!black, 
            blue!60, 
            red!70,
            gray!70,
            teal!20},
        text = legend   % Add a legend
        ]   % Values:
        {
            20/Report Writing + Documentation,
            10/Reaction Wheel design,
            30/Components testing,
            40/HiL control algorithm testing and optimization
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
 
\end{document}
```

whereas this fails:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} % Pie chart library

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Work}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \pie[
      color={yellow!90!black, 
...
```

note the line break after `\pie[`

Just removing the linebreak isn't quite enough, it needs to be `\pie[color...`

For those trying to debug this, there is a hint in the error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/ color', to which you pass
ed 'yellow!90!black, green!60!black, blue!60, red!70, gray!70, teal!20', and I 
am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Note how it says `'/pgf/ color'` keys normally do not start or end with a space.

I don't know why it wasn't removed automatically, perhaps others can answer that.

Comment: Thanks! Gosh it was that! Have been searching all Google for this!
Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: @YiQiangJi they can be a bit hard to debug at times. But note that the error actually include a space, I'll update my answer with that information.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, it is safe to type something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  option1 = a,
  option2 = b,
]
<code>
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but apparently this is not allowed with `\pie` that doesn't consume the space generated by the endline and, indeed, the error message is about the key

```
pgf/ color
```

not being defined.

You can solve it by remembering to type

```
\pie[%
  color={...},
  text={...}
]
```

or you can take a step forward: inform the developers of Ti*k*Z/PGF about the inconsistency and, for the time being, fix the definition so that it consumes a possible space.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} % Pie chart library
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@pgfpie@@pie\pgfpie@@pie
\def\pgfpie@@pie[#1]#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \orig@pgfpie@@pie[]{#2}%
  \else
    \expandafter\orig@pgfpie@@pie\expandafter[\@firstofone #1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Work}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\scalebox{0.8}{% <--- don't forget
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[
      color = {
        yellow!90!black, 
        green!60!black, 
        blue!60, 
        red!70,
        gray!70,
        teal!20
      },
      text = legend   % Add a legend
    ] % Values:
    {
     20/Report Writing + Documentation,
     10/Reaction Wheel design,
     30/Components testing,
     40/HiL control algorithm testing and optimization
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}% <--- don't forget
}

\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Work organisation. Source: Own.}
\label{fig:work_pie_chart}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my opinion it would be better to scale just the pie chart and not the text.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} % Pie chart library
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@pgfpie@@pie\pgfpie@@pie
\def\pgfpie@@pie[#1]#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \orig@pgfpie@@pie[]{#2}%
  \else
    \expandafter\orig@pgfpie@@pie\expandafter[\@firstofone #1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Work}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \pie[
      color = {
        yellow!90!black, 
        green!60!black, 
        blue!60, 
        red!70,
        gray!70,
        teal!20
      },
      text = legend   % Add a legend
    ] % Values:
    {
     20/Report Writing + Documentation,
     10/Reaction Wheel design,
     30/Components testing,
     40/HiL control algorithm testing and optimization
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Work organisation. Source: Own.}
\label{fig:work_pie_chart}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `[H]` specifier does nothing (and should almost never be used anyway). And it's not really useful to have a figure environment: note the unqualified “Figure:” part that's just useless for the audience. And the `\label` would refer to no sensible value.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} % Pie chart library
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@pgfpie@@pie\pgfpie@@pie
\def\pgfpie@@pie[#1]#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \orig@pgfpie@@pie[]{#2}%
  \else
    \expandafter\orig@pgfpie@@pie\expandafter[\@firstofone #1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Work}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
  \pie[
    color = {
      yellow!90!black, 
      green!60!black, 
      blue!60, 
      red!70,
      gray!70,
      teal!20
    },
    text = legend   % Add a legend
  ] % Values:
  {
   20/Report Writing + Documentation,
   10/Reaction Wheel design,
   30/Components testing,
   40/HiL control algorithm testing and optimization
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

Work organisation. Source: Own.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the good practices and help! I woud definitely take them into account